# Trying to only load function when source is a jpg

Tags: javascript

As an exercise, I'm trying to make a hoverzoom script in Javascript without resorting to jQuery. The script puts all the `<a>` links on the page in an array, then searches for `href` with an extension of `jpg` and applies a hoverzoom function to it

I'm very close to getting it working. The function works fine for instances where the `<a>` filename DOES end in jpg, but when it ends in something different the code breaks. Here's the offending code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aLinks.length; i++) {
    aExtensions[i] = aLinks[i].href.split('.').pop();
    if (aExtensions[i].toLowerCase() == 'jpg') {
        aImages.push(aLinks[i]);
    }
    aImages[i].onmouseover = function() {
        hoverZoom(this);
    }
    aImages[i].onmouseout = function() {
        refresh(this);
    }
}
```

The full script plus a live version is here: http://james.is.agoodman.com.au/git/js_hoverZoom/

As you can see in the live demo it works for the two image links, breaks on the third non-image link, and then the subsequent image links don't work either.

EDIT: Apologies, forgot to specify a question. How can I alter the script to only function when the source extension matches .jpg, and do nothing when the extension doesn't match?

Comment: And the question is? Are you sure pushing to an array, then using that array inside the loop to attach event handlers is a good idea.

Comment: I think you need to put the event bindings into the `if` statement...You're not binding the events based on the `if` statement - you're always accessing `aImages[i]`, which may or may not be set

Comment: @adeneo is that a bad idea? I'm very new to Javascript, so please excuse the obvious mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the event bindings into the `if` statement:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aLinks.length; i++) {
    aExtensions[i] = aLinks[i].href.split('.').pop();
    if (aExtensions[i].toLowerCase() == 'jpg') {
        aLinks[i].onmouseover = function() {
            hoverZoom(this);
        };
        aLinks[i].onmouseout = function() {
            refresh(this);
        };
        aImages.push(aLinks[i]);
    }
}
```

You aren't *always* pushing an item to the `aImages` array, so `aImages[i]` won't *always* be something. Moving the event bindings into the `if` statement and rearranging guarantees that the extension is "jpg", and therefore binds an event to an existing item, then pushes it into `aImages`

Comment: And if it does'nt always push an image to the array, the indices will be off and not match the content of the array.

Comment: @adeneo Reread my answer. I don't push the item in the array or reference it until after the event bindings. I reference the original `aLinks` array item for event bindings, then push that item into `aImages`

Comment: Smart move, did'nt really see that at first no!

Comment: @adeneo No problem, I realized simply moving the event bindings into the `for` loop would create the problem you mention, so it took an extra rearrangement to fix that

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the way you're indexing your loop: you should use seperate loops to create the  aImages array and then loop through it: something like this should work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aLinks.length; i++) {
    aExtensions[i] = aLinks[i].href.split('.').pop();
    if (aExtensions[i].toLowerCase() == 'jpg') {
        aImages.push(aLinks[i]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < aImages.length; i++) {
    aImages[i].onmouseover = function() {
        hoverZoom(this);
    }
    aImages[i].onmouseout = function() {
        refresh(this);
    }
}
```

Otherwise the non-image links knock your indexing out of sync

Answer (score 1):

When the function encounters a non jpg file, it will skip the if block, but will try to find that link in aImages array. Which will break the code.

You should either write a different for loop, or better approach will be bind the events in if block.